# signalR hubs error 500 on local host but works on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

im locally not able to get data from signalR,on the network-element of browser  i see it gives error 500 on hubs,but when i run on the server it works,is there something i should add to work on localhost?i already added the following on webconfig but still error 500 i get:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

the scripts im referencing are like this:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js")" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
```

Comment: Did you install web-sockets in IIS?

Comment: @Neos no how should i do it?

Comment: Go to the Server Manager > Manage > Add Roles and Features > Web Server > Application Development > Websockets.

Comment: @Neos i have enabled it,but still the same

Comment: developer tool of web browser it shows, localhost/signalr/hubs error 500